# error: the left-hand side must be a variable

Tags: java

Eclipse is giving me the error "The left-hand side must be a variable" at this part of my code:

```
else 
    { for(int i=0; i>=cellphoneArr.length; i++)
       {if (cell_1.equals2(cellphoneArr[i]))
           System.out.println(cellphoneArr[i]);
       else 
           (cell_1.equals3(cellphoneArr[i])); ---> this is the error
            System.out.println(cellphoneArr[i]);

       }
```

The method equals3 is the following:

```
    public boolean equals3(Cellphone phone)
{ if (brand.equals(phone));
}
```

I've been trying to figure this one out, but the way I invoked my two other methods equals 1 and 2 both worked with the object cell_1.

Comment: what is `cell_1` and where is the method `equals3` declared. Also you should use proper indentation, as is it's hard to read.

Comment: nevermind, I just realized my constructor has no return value. Please ignore this question... it is too late to work on a project.

Comment: Sorry I didn't want to put all my code in here, it would be a bother for people I thought

Comment: Is that the exact message? It says precisely "The left-hand side must be a variable" and nothing else?

Answer (score 1):

Try it as:

```
else 
{ for(int i=0; i>=cellphoneArr.length; i++)
   {if (cell_1.equals2(cellphoneArr[i]))
       System.out.println(cellphoneArr[i]);
   else if(cell_1.equals3(cellphoneArr[i]))
        System.out.println(cellphoneArr[i]);
   }
```

and the method equals3 must return a boolean values as:

```
public boolean equals3(Cellphone phone)
{ if (brand.equals(phone))
  return true;
  else
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an if following the else

**EDIT**

The code should be

```
if (cell_1.equals2(cellphoneArr[i])) {
  System.out.println(cellphoneArr[i]);
} else if (cell_1.equals3(cellphoneArr[i])) {
  System.out.println(cellphoneArr[i]);
}
```

Formatting allows you to pin point these kind of errors easily. If you are using Eclipse, do ctrl + shift + f

Answer (score 0):

Remove `;` at the end of `else`, Just like you did for `if`.

```
else(cell_1.equals3(cellphoneArr[i]));
                                     ^
```

Return a Boolean value from you function, instead of `if`

```
public boolean equals3(Cellphone phone)
{ 
  return (brand.equals(phone));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `if`:

```
else if (cell_1.equals3(cellphoneArr[i]))
```